# Android sleep() without blocking UI

Tags: android, sleep, thread-sleep

For my new Android application I need a function, that timeout my application for 3 Seconds. I tried the function "sleep()" like this:

```
seekBar1.setProgress(50);                // Set something for my SeekBar

try{
   Thread.sleep(3000);                   // Wait for 3 Seconds
} catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println("Error: "+e);      // Catch the exception
}

button.setEnabled(true);                 // Enable my button
```

It seems to work, but if I was running the application it does it like this: Wait for 3 Seconds, set progress and enable button. I want first to set the progress and then wait for 3 seconds and only then to enable the button.

Is "sleep()" for the right for my use or what can I do else that my application does it in the right order?

Comment: You can use handler `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               button.setEnable(true); 
            }
        },3000);`

Comment: If it works for you, just use it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `postDelayed()` method like this:

```
handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //what ever you do here will be done after 3 seconds delay.              
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever block the ui thread with a sleep.  Its ok to sleep on another thread, but even then it should be avoided.  The right way to do this is to post a Runnable to a Handler.  Then put whatever code you want to run after the delay in the run() method of the Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `Handle` in your Activity and use `Handle.postDelayed()` from Activity's `onCreate()`so you receive a message on that handle in 3 seconds. Upon receving you can enable the button.

You can do the same using `AsyncTask` where in `doInBackground()` you just sleep for 3 sec. Then in `onPostExecute()` you enable the button.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the AsyncTask idea.  Creating a new Thread is rather heavyweight for a 3 second delay.  The Handler is the right way to do it.

Comment: Also, AsyncTaks run one after another on a single thread, so if another AsyncTask is running this new one may not be called for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Use object of Handler class and use method handler.postDelayed(thread,time).Don't use sleep() it will block ui thread.